# Can anybody help me implement hybrid embedding model using keras library as shown in the attached figure

Tags: keras

I am confused that how to process character level information in RNN using keras. I want to implement something like this [model structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmSBW.jpg).
I have 1800 sentences; each sentence length(time_stamp) 150 and each word length has 16 characters. Gensim model helps me to create word embedding of the size of 100. Unique characters in sentences are 69, for each character represented by one hot encoding is 70.

shape for word-level bi-lstm input is: sentences X time_stamp X embedding_size (1800 x 150 x 100)
I know that how to feed this into keras layer but I am confused with character level feeding. the shape for char-level is: sentences X time_stamp X characters X char_embedding (1800 x 150 x 16 x 70).
I am a beginner in for keras.

Comment: You need to be far more specific to get help.

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the image is a simple bi-directional LSTM:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidrectional(LSTM(128), input_shape=(maxlen, len(chars))))
# Bidrectional concatenates the output of both directions by default.
```

For a more full example you can check the [text generation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_text_generation.py) example which uses character level processing.